# how to make changes on the main page of the website based on the url TYPED by the user in the address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am working on a single page website with asp.net as the server side technology
I want to create an experience like the one seen in [this website](http://www.ascensionlatorre.com/).
 As you can see, when the user scrolls the page, the url changes dynamically and the `navbar` shows where the user is in the page.By clicking each `navbar` item, the page scrolls to the right section and the url changes again based on the content.
Clearly this site is using  javascript's history api (history.js in this context) and I am totally familiar with how these apis work in javascript

My main problem is this: when a user types in the url in the address bar, I want my main page to act as if the user clicked a link in the page and scroll to that specific part. For example when the user types www.mysite.com/products, I want the main page to be shown to the user and the page automatically scroll to the products section of the page

Is there some kind of routing trick I have to implement on the server side? Cause currently by typing urls like the one I showed above, I get a `404 not found` response (which logically is correct since there is only the main page in my website's root folder and no products folder for example)

How can I achieve my goal? thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: you need to have pages at any url used by your app, or else you get a 404. ex: `view-source:http://www.ascensionlatorre.com/collection` is a real page

Comment: also, there is no way to get the value of anything in the address bar from JS, one can only set it, or ask about the last inputed+nav'd parsed result URI; ie you can't spot typing, only what they typed...

Comment: Then let me ask this, suppose you are in the products real page at www.mysite.com/products and now you scroll to a different section of the page and the url should be www.mysite.com/section.how do you achieve that? Since with using history.push state(section) the url becoms www.mysite.com/products/section

Comment: you can serve the same html on all "pages", just examine the url onload() to update the "active" nav. in fact, you could simply re-direct to a given page from all those urls, or any urls in general with an htaccess mod. you just need to be able to determine the intent during pageload, and setup the site to highlight that part, setting the url again if needed.

Comment: ok I got part of your solution.But what can I do int his scenario: The user is in www.mysite.com/products REAL page.Now he scrolls the page to another section.How do you change the url to www.mysite.com/section and not www.mysite.com/products/section ?

Comment: `history.replaceState(null, null, "/section")`